# HTML5 canvas drawing, allow multiple touch inputs

Tags: html, html5-canvas, multi-touch

I would like to create an web based guestbook for an 84" multi-touch device. I know how to create a canvas which allows a user to draw, but I wonder if the same is possible for multiple users? I have found some information on html5 multi-touch input, but all of it is related to gestures.

Since the surface is large enough and the device supports it, ideally I would like for several users to draw something onto the canvas simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, the number of users will depend on the number of touchpoints the device can handle. Most I have come across handle 5 touch points, so that means 5 people can draw at once.You will have to turn of touch actions eg CSS `body {touch-action : none;}` to prevent standard gestures from interfering.

Comment: Alright thanks! And how could I differentiate between the different input events?

Comment: You can not, each time a new touch comes down it is in order of number of touches. Could be any finger or any person.

Answer (score 0):

Here is whole program. There is no nothing to `allow multiple touch inputs`.
You only need to access `event.changedTouches`

Navigate with mobile device and test demo.
I made also button click detection example (HUB BUTTON).

Source: https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/multi-touch-canvas-handler/blob/master/index.html

```js
function MOBILE_CONTROL () {
 
  this.X =  null;
  this.Y =  null;
  this.LAST_X_POSITION = null;
  this.LAST_Y_POSITION = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH = 'NO';
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 = null;  
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 = null;  
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X8 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 = null;
  this.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = 1;
  this.SCREEN = [window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight]; 
  this.SCREEN.W = this.SCREEN[0];
  this.SCREEN.H = this.SCREEN[1];
  
  //Application general
  this.AUTOR = "Nikola Lukic";
  this.APPLICATION_NAME = "TestApplication";
  
  this.SET_APPLICATION_NAME = function (value) {
            if (typeof value != 'string')
                throw 'APPLICATION_NAME must be a string!';
            if (value.length < 2 || value.length > 20)
                throw 'APPLICATION_NAME must be 2-20 characters long!';
            this.APPLICATION_NAME = value;
        };
  this.APP = function(){/*construct*/};
  this.APP.BODY = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  this.APP.BODY.SET_STYLE = function (string) {this.style = string;}
  this.APP.BODY.SET_BACKGROUND_COLOR = function (color) {this.style.backgroundColor = color;}
  this.APP.BODY.SET_COLOR = function (color) {this.style.Color = color;} 
  this.APP.BODY.ADD_DIV = function (id , style , innerHTML) { 
   var n = document.createElement('div');
   var divIdName = id;
   n.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
   n.setAttribute('style',style);
   n.innerHTML = innerHTML;
   this.appendChild(n);
  };
  this.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS = function (id,width_,height_) { 
   var n = document.createElement('canvas');
   var divIdName = id;
   n.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
   n.setAttribute('width',width_);
   n.setAttribute('height',height_);
   //n.innerHTML = 'Element is here';
   this.appendChild(n);
  };
  console.log('<MOBILE_CONTROL JavaScript class>');
  console.log('status:MOBILE_CONTROL FINISH LOADING');
  console.log('EASY_IMPLEMENTATION!');
  
}

function CANVAS_DRAW() {
  var run = true;
  var timer = null;
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', MDPORT, false); 
  function MDPORT(){
  if (run) {
   clearInterval(timer);
   run = false;
  } else {
   timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
   run = true;
 }
}

var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
var UPDOWN = 1,CONTROL_WIDTH = 0;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

setInterval(randomColor, 5000);

timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);

function randomColor() {
 r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function makeHarmonograph() {
f1 = (f1  / 10) % 10;
f2 = (f2 / 40) % 10;
f3 = (f3 + Math.random() / 80) % 10;
f4 = (f4 + Math.random() / 411) % 10;
p1 += 0.5 % (Math.PI*2)
drawHarmonograph();
}

function drawHarmonograph() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 850, 450);

ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1100, 400);
 
ctx.translate(511, 0);
ctx.rotate(1.57);
///////////
 // Draw guides
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';
 ctx.lineWidth = A1 ;
 
 ctx.translate(111, 1);
 ctx.rotate(0.01);
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN+1;}
 if (UPDOWN>51){CONTROL_WIDTH=1; } 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN-0.1;}
 if (UPDOWN<1){CONTROL_WIDTH=0; } 
 
 // Set line styles
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#099909';
 ctx.lineWidth = UPDOWN;
 
 // check input
 ctx.miterLimit = UPDOWN;
 
 // Draw lines
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(111,100);
 for (i=0;i<121;i++){
 var dy = i%2==0 ? 25 : -25 ;
 ctx.lineTo(Math.pow(i,1.5)*2,75+dy);
 }
 ctx.stroke();
 return false;
 
ctx.translate(444, 333);
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Overlapping harmonics with JavaScript, wait secund.",5,25);

 
ctx.stroke();
 

}




}

function CANVAS_DRAW_1(){
var run = true;
var timer = null;


 
timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);
run = true;
 


var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
var UPDOWN = 1,CONTROL_WIDTH = 0;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_1").getContext("2d");

setInterval(randomColor, 5000);

timer = setInterval(makeHarmonograph, 1);

function randomColor() {
r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function makeHarmonograph() {
f1 = (f1  / 10) % 10;
f2 = (f2 / 40) % 10;
f3 = (f3 + Math.random() / 80) % 10;
f4 = (f4 + Math.random() / 411) % 10;
p1 += 0.5 % (Math.PI*2)
drawHarmonograph();
}

function drawHarmonograph() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 850, 450);
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
ctx.translate(0, 250);
ctx.beginPath();
if (A1 > 100) {}
for (var t = 0; t < 100; t+=0.1) {

var x = A1 * Math.sin(f1 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d1 * t) + A2 * Math.sin(f2 * t + Math.PI * p2) * Math.exp(-d2 * t);
var y = A3 * Math.sin(f3 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d3 * t) + A4 * Math.sin(f4 * t + Math.PI * p4) * Math.exp(-d4 * t);

//ctx.lineTo(x*x, y/x);
ctx.lineTo(x*x+1, y+1/x);

}

ctx.stroke();
ctx.translate(A1, 0);
ctx.rotate(1.57);
ctx.beginPath();

for (var t = 0; t < 100; t+=0.1) {

var x = A1 * A3* Math.sin(f1 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d1 * t) + A2 * Math.sin(f2 * t + Math.PI * p2) * Math.exp(-d2 * t);
var y = A3 * Math.sin(f3 * t + Math.PI * p1) * Math.exp(-d3 * t) + A4 * Math.sin(f4 * t + Math.PI * p4) * Math.exp(-d4 * t);

ctx.lineTo(x*x+1, y+1/x);

}

ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

 // Draw guides
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';
 ctx.lineWidth = A1;
 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN+1;}
 if (UPDOWN>51){CONTROL_WIDTH=1; } 
 if (CONTROL_WIDTH == 0) { UPDOWN=UPDOWN-0.1;}
 if (UPDOWN<1){CONTROL_WIDTH=0; } 
 
 // Set line styles
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#099909';
 ctx.lineWidth = UPDOWN;
 
 // check input
 ctx.miterLimit = 5;
 
 // Draw lines
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,100);
 for (i=0;i<124;i++){
 var dy = i%2==0 ? 25 : -25 ;
 ctx.lineTo(Math.pow(i,1.5)*2,75+dy);
 }
 ctx.stroke();
 return false;
 
ctx.translate(A1, 210);
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Overlapping harmonics with JavaScript, wait secund.",5,25);

}

}


function CANVAS_DRAW_2(){
 
var timer = null;
  
 
var A1 = 200, f1 = 2, p1 = 1/16, d1 = 0.02;
var A2 = 10, f2 = 4, p2 = 3 / 2, d2 = 0.0315;
var A3 = 200, f3 = 4, p3 = 13 / 15, d3 = 0.00012;
var A4 = 10, f4 = 4, p4 = 1, d4 = 0.012;
var r = 10, g =10, b = 0;
 
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_2").getContext("2d");

setInterval(randomColor, 5000);

timer = setInterval(t, 1);

function randomColor() {
 r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function t() {     
 r1();
}

function r1() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CONTROL.SCREEN.W, CONTROL.SCREEN.H);
ctx.save();
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, CONTROL.SCREEN.W, CONTROL.SCREEN.H);

 
ctx.beginPath();
 
 
var x = CONTROL.X;
var y = CONTROL.Y;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
 
ctx.fillRect(x, y-400, 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(x-400, y, 2500, 1);
ctx.fillText(" ( targetX:" + CONTROL.X + " ( targetY: "+ CONTROL.Y + " ) ",x,y);

ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
ctx.font="10px Arial";
ctx.fillText(" JavaScript ",x- CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3.4);
ctx.fillText(" welcome here , canvas example with MOBILE_TOUCH() ",x -  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3.2);
ctx.fillText(" no css files need, pure js ",x -  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/3,y - CONTROL.SCREEN.H/3);



if (CONTROL.X > CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2 && CONTROL.X < CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2 + 300 && CONTROL.Y > CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2 && CONTROL.Y < CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2 + 100) {

ctx.strokeStyle = "lime";
}
else{
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
}
ctx.strokeRect( CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2.2, CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2.2, 300, 100);
ctx.fillText(" HUB DETECT ",  CONTROL.SCREEN.W/2, CONTROL.SCREEN.H/2);



if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_51 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 , 2500, 1);
}
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 !== 'undefined'){
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10-400  , 1, 2500);
ctx.fillRect(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 -400 , CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 , 2500, 1);
}
 
 // Draw lines
  
ctx.fillStyle='lime';
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("MOBILE_TOUCH example ",5,25);
 
}



}


//definition
var CONTROL = new MOBILE_CONTROL();

//CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas");
//CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas_1");
CONTROL.APP.BODY.ADD_2DCANVAS("canvas_2",CONTROL.SCREEN.W,CONTROL.SCREEN.H);

CONTROL.APP.BODY.SET_STYLE('margin-left:-10px;padding:0;border:none;');
//CANVAS_DRAW();
//CANVAS_DRAW_1();
CANVAS_DRAW_2();
 
//<!-- SCREEN.prototype.sayHello = function(){alert ('hello' + "sss" );}; -->

//###################################################################
//EVENTS
//###################################################################  
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) 
{ 
 
if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'NO') {

    var touch = event.touches[0];
    CONTROL.X = touch.pageX;
    CONTROL.Y = touch.pageY;
    console.log('TOUCH START AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
    
}
else if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'YES') {


  var touches_changed = event.changedTouches;
   
   for (var i=0; i<touches_changed.length;i++) {
   
   //CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1
  console.log("multi touch : x" + CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + ":(" +touches_changed[i].pageX + ")");
  switch(CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX)
{
case 1:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 2:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 3:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 4:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 5:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 6:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 7:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 8:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 9:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 10:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
default:
  //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + 1;
  
  
  }

}

CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH = 'YES';
 
},false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) 
{ 
var touch = event.touches[0];
CONTROL.X = touch.pageX;
CONTROL.Y = touch.pageY;
console.log('TOUCH MOVE AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );

//#############
 if (CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH == 'YES') {


  var touches_changed = event.changedTouches;
   
   for (var i=0; i<touches_changed.length;i++) {
   
   //CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1
  console.log("multi touch : x" + CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX + ":(" +touches_changed[i].pageX + ")");
  switch(i)
{
case 1:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 2:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 3:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 4:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 5:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 6:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 7:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 8:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 9:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
case 10:
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10=touches_changed[i].pageX;
  CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10=touches_changed[i].pageY;
  break;
default:
  //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
}}

//#############


event.preventDefault();

},false);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
document.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) 
{ 
CONTROL.LAST_X_POSITION = CONTROL.X;  
CONTROL.LAST_Y_POSITION = CONTROL.Y; 
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH = 'NO';
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_INDEX = 1;

CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X1 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X2 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X3 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X4 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X5 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X6 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X7 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X8 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X9 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_X10 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y1 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y2 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y3 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y4 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y5 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y6 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y7 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y8 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y9 = null;
CONTROL.MULTI_TOUCH_Y10 = null;

console.log('LAST TOUCH POSITION AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '),(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
},false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(event) 
{ 
console.log('BREAK - LAST TOUCH POSITION AT:(X' + CONTROL.X + '(,(' + CONTROL.Y + ')' );
}, false);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```